# Trying to vonvert 2d array into 1d array,can somebody help me

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can somebody help me to convert 2d array into 1d array?
2d array compilied randomnly.Also i am new to c#,and yes,i am sorry for my english)
Thanks!

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
        int[,] lala = new int[5, 6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                lala[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                Console.Write(lala[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        int i, j;
        int[] b = new int[30];
        int k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                b[k++] = lala[i, j];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 5 * 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 as the loop limits in the 2nd loop? They should be 5 and 6 also.

Comment: Ok, you've edited that. Now you should be getting some errors about `i` and `j`. I would get rid of `int i, j;` and change all the `for` loops to declare them each time: `for (int i....` and `for (int j...`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry i cant understand what i need exactly to change,cant you send me a code of it?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp can you help me to conver final 1d array back to 2d array?

Comment: You can use the same nested loops with `lala[i, j] = b[i * 6 + j];`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to somehow put values of 2D array into 1D - here is one way

```
int upper1 = 5;
int upper2 = 6;
int[,] twoD = new int[upper1, upper2];
// fill array

int[] oneD = new int[upper1 * upper2];
int idx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < upper1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < upper2; j++)
    {
        oneD[++idx] = twoD[i,j]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[,] lala = new int[5, 6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                lala[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                Console.Write(lala[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        //int i, j;
        int[] b = new int[30];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                b[k++] = lala[i, j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 * 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Your error was that in the 'i' and 'j' variables declaration. I recommend you to declare a variable in the context you wanna use it, and not reuse it out of that context.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one-liner using the Linq extension methods `Cast` and `ToArray` will do the trick. I believe `Cast` just takes every item in the array (from all dimensions), casts them to the specified type, and returns them in an `IEnumerable` (which `ToArray` then converts into an array):

```
int[] oneDimensionalArray = twoDimensionalArray.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

---

Another way you can do this is with a `foreach` loop, which will iterate through both dimensions of your two dimensional array:

```
int index = 0;

foreach (var item in twoDimensionalArray)
{
    oneDimensionalArray[index++] = item;
}
```

Code sample:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var rowCount = 10;
var colCount = 10;

// Populate two dimensional array. You could also use this "double for loop" structure 
// to read the multi-dimensional array and then populate the one dimensional array.
var twoD = new int[rowCount, colCount];

for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    for (var col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
    {
        twoD[row, col] = rnd.Next();
    }
}

// Populate one dimensional array with a foreach loop. Use a separate 
//  hold the index value for the one dimentional array
var oneD = new int[rowCount * colCount];
var index = 0;

foreach (var item in twoD)
{
    oneD[index++] = item;
}
```